# WKWebView issues with constraints when keyboard is displayed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

Keyboard does not work when prompted when focusing on an input field from WKWebView and I wonder how to set the constraints to avoid this issue

The page is loading just fine. On the page, there is an input field. When I click on the input field, the keyboard pops up but the focus on the field is not set anymore and nothing can be inputed. xcode gives the following error log:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  setupWebView()
}

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
  self.showWebView()
}

func showWebView() {
        webView.frame = view.frame
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(webView)

view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[webView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["webView":webView]))
        view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-20-[webView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(), metrics: nil, views: ["webView":webView]))

    }

    func setupWebView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

        webView = WKWebView(frame:.zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView?.navigationDelegate = self

        //Disable scroll of WebView
        webView.scrollView.bounces = false

        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let url = URL(string: self.url)
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        print(request)
        webView.load(request)
    }
```

Error log:

```
2019-02-11 15:53:46.940718+0100 AppName[9824:4549339] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

2019-02-11 15:53:46.943297+0100 AppName[9824:4549339] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.

2019-02-11 15:53:47.085142+0100 AppName[9824:4549339] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x113d03880; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x28017c800>> returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric

2019-02-11 15:53:47.085268+0100 AppName[9824:4549339] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x113d03880; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x28017c800>> returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
2019-02-11 15:53:47.123997+0100 AppName[9824:4549339] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
  Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
  Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
  (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x282275ae0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIToolbarContentView:0x113d3d9e0.width == UIToolbar:0x113d3d5a0.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282262bc0 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x113d3f970]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x113d3d9e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2822637a0 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x113d3f970.trailing == _UIToolbarContentView:0x113d3d9e0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282273cf0 H:|-(16)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x113d54b00]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d546b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282273d40 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x113d54b00]-(>=8)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d546b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282278320 H:|-(>=5)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x113d56e30]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d567e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282278370 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x113d56e30]-(>=5)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d567e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282278dc0 H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x113d57ee0'Done']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d57350 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282278e10 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x113d57ee0'Done']-(16)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d57350 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282275090 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x2838457a0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading == _UIButtonBarButton:0x113d546b0.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2822750e0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x2838457a0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == _UIButtonBarButton:0x113d57350.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282275130 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d546b0]-(0)-[UIView:0x113d56600]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282275180 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x113d56600]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d567e0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2822751d0 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d567e0]-(0)-[UIView:0x113d57170]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282275220 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x113d57170]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d57350]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282275c70 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIToolbar:0x113d3d5a0.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2822699f0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x2838457a0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x113d3f970 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282269a90 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x2838457a0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x113d3f970 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282273d40 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x113d54b00]-(>=8)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d546b0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.



2019-02-11 15:53:47.134917+0100 AppName[9824:4549339] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
  Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
  Try this: 
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
  (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x282275ae0 h=-&- v=-&- _UIToolbarContentView:0x113d3d9e0.width == UIToolbar:0x113d3d5a0.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282262bc0 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x113d3f970]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x113d3d9e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2822637a0 _UIButtonBarStackView:0x113d3f970.trailing == _UIToolbarContentView:0x113d3d9e0.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282278320 H:|-(>=5)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x113d56e30]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d567e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282278370 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x113d56e30]-(>=5)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d567e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282278dc0 H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x113d57ee0'Done']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d57350 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282278e10 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x113d57ee0'Done']-(16)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d57350 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282275090 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x2838457a0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading == _UIButtonBarButton:0x113d546b0.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2822750e0 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x2838457a0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == _UIButtonBarButton:0x113d57350.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282275130 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d546b0]-(0)-[UIView:0x113d56600]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282275180 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x113d56600]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d567e0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2822751d0 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d567e0]-(0)-[UIView:0x113d57170]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282275220 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x113d57170]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d57350]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282275c70 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UIToolbar:0x113d3d5a0.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2822699f0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x2838457a0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x113d3f970 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282269a90 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x2838457a0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x113d3f970 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x282278370 H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x113d56e30]-(>=5)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x113d567e0 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I have spent hours on this now without any successful result. I have read multiple similar threads without any good answer. My app was working just fine, but suddenly this problem occurred from nowhere. Would be happy for some guidance

Comment: I have the same issue of this question. I just only have a wkwebview in my storyboard, and set top,left,bottom,right constrains equal to superview boarder.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. constraints are set correctly but still constraint error are coming while toolbar appear from input field.

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard to tell what is wrong with your constraints without looking at the storyboard. Sometimes it helps if you clear all the constraints and add them again, thinking about which element needs to stick to what. Changing the "View as..." to see the view on different screen sizes in the storyboard helps to visualize where you went wrong.